# Prevent vertical scroll on iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I have a mobile website that has a main wrapper with three divs inside - all are fixed height which add up to 480px total. The top two divs inside are headers which are pretty short, and the bottom one is where the main content is and has an overflow-y of scroll. I set the html and body to overflow-y:hidden. I want only the main content div to scroll vertically and absolutely nothing else, leaving the headers always visible in full.

When I view it in my desktop browser it works fine. In my iPhone simulator it scrolls correctly if I click and drag within that content div, but if I click and drag from one of the headers or I swipe with two fingers on my trackpad it scrolls the whole page, not just the content. This results in the top header getting scrolled off the page. I don't have a real iphone to test with, but I am told by my client that the same thing happens on her iphone.

I tried setting the height of the main wrapper to something very short (300px) so in theory there shouldn't be any need to scroll the page at all regardless of the overflow setting, but it still scrolls. I also tried visiting [this very short page](http://www.topsite.com/goto/dwarfurl.com) and even there in the simulator it scrolls a little. I also tried setting my headers to position:fixed but no luck.

How can I get the page to stop scrolling away from the headers?

Comment: max-height on what? I already set a fixed height.

Comment: max-height that is to be set for the maximum scroll?

Answer (score 2):

You could bind a "touchmove" event to the two other divs, and use prevent default.

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The use jQuery and

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $("#header").on(‘touchmove’, function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
   $("#footer").on(‘touchmove’, function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
}
```

This will prevent the browser from doing it’s default behaviour.